# Loop that calculates phylogenetic signal for each column of a trait data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the phylogenetic signal of my functional traits, therefore calculate it. Because of the size of the data frame, I was thinking of creating a loop. I want the loop to run through each column of `data_df`.

The basic function runs like this:

```
library(picante)

trait_1 <- trait_df[,1]
names(trait_1) <- rownames(trait_df)
physig_1 <- phylosig(phylo_tree, setNames(trait_1, rownames(trait_1)), method = "lambda", test = T, nsim=99)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to calculate the K-statistic and the p value of the phylogenetic signal for every column of taxa metadata table `mammal.data` considering the tree `mammal.tree`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(phytools)
#> Loading required package: ape
#> Loading required package: maps
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'maps'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     map

data(mammal.tree)
data(mammal.data)

mammal.data %>%
  as.list() %>%
  lapply(function(trait) {
    names(trait) <- rownames(mammal.data)
    res <- phylosig(mammal.tree, trait, test=TRUE)
    
    list(
      P = res$P,
      K = res$K
    )
  }) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_auto(value)
#> Using `unnest_wider(value)`; elements have 2 names in common
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   name          P     K
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 bodyMass  0.001 0.800
#> 2 homeRange 0.551 0.115
```

This procedure can also be adapted to the lambda method, which output different numbers:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(phytools)
#> Loading required package: ape
#> Loading required package: maps
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'maps'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     map

data(mammal.tree)
data(mammal.data)

mammal.data %>%
  as.list() %>%
  lapply(function(trait) {
    names(trait) <- rownames(mammal.data)
    res <- phylosig(mammal.tree, trait, method = "lambda", test=TRUE)
    
    list(
      lambda = res$lambda,
      logL = res$logL,
      logL0 = res$logL0,
      P = res$P
    )
  }) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_auto(value)
#> Using `unnest_wider(value)`; elements have 4 names in common
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   name      lambda  logL logL0        P
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 bodyMass  1.01   -332. -359. 1.74e-13
#> 2 homeRange 0.0554 -270. -270. 6.00e- 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I am using pagel's λ to calculate the phylogenetic signal, is it going to be different?

Comment: @PanagiotaFolla I updated my answer to include the lambda method as well

Comment: it is the first time I see a nested structure, so I am having one more question: how do I export that as a data frame?

Comment: This is already a data.frame (with sub-class tibble). Assign it to a variable e.g. with `signals <- mammal.data %>% as.list() %>% lapply...`